# Flask-JWT or Flask-Login

Tags: python, flask, backend, flask-login, flask-jwt

I am trying to build a Flask backend with REST but I am unsure to use Flask-JWT or Flask-Login for managing user logins and authorization. I thought of using it both. **Can I do so?** If I can, then should I use **@jwt_required() or **@login_required** decorator?

Comment: NOTE for newcomers: use instead, the Flask-JWT-Extended, which is found https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/, has been updated more recently and has better documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [flask-jwt-extended](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basic_usage/) package. It comes with very handy basic and advanced examples for using JSON Webtokens. The example I've linked uses a single decorator `jwt_required`.

And if you require re-authentication, there's an example using a `refresh_token`.
https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/token_freshness/

Be sure to read up on website authentication. Here's a good place to start:

- [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication)

But try keep it simple to start.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was helpful. But I actually wonder whether I still need Flask-Login when I use Flask-JWT/Flask-JWT-Extended, or not.

Comment: Here is a thread directly relevant to your case: https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/issues/253